# rake task running in cron can't find database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, whenever

I have created the cron job with whenever (https://github.com/javan/whenever):

```
every 1.hours do
   rake "scrape" 
end
```

The rake scrape task runs fine when I run it manually, but when cron runs I get:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'beskeds'
```

The command run is:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/klaus/Documents/src/Ruby/rails/fintra && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake scrape --silent'
```

I am using RVM by the way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK I got it now.
It turns out I am only running this site on my own computer and have no production environment and hence no production database...

The whenever configuration should be:

```
every 1.hours do
   rake "scrape", environment => "development"
end
```

I also had to run whenever with the environment:

```
whenever -w --set environment=development
```

Comment: Plus one for answering your own question and posting for others